# Android ImageView Is Not Displaying Image?

Tags: java, android, imageview

Can anyone tell me why the following code is not working? The Image does not appear at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"

   <ImageView
          android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
          android:scaleType="center"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: RelativeLayout does not have an orientation.....

Comment: If you run the app in Android Api 21 or below, it is a common problem. Mainly, it is because you use high resolution, large dimension images. I recommend you to resize, shrink your images.

Comment: worked for me thanks!

Answer (score 41):

In ImageView there is two options **src** and **srcCompact**. Try both of them to find out which is working.

```
android:src="@drawable/slide_view_4"
```

and

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/slide_view_4"
```

Comment: Great ! Working for me

Comment: This is the answer that works in Android SDK 33. I had to app:srcCompat for android:src

Answer (score 35):

In my case, all my fragment's imageViews are not showing when I run my application. The problem is, I extend my "**Activity**" class from "**FragmentActivity**". so I just change it "**FragmentActivity**" to "**AppCompatActivity**"

maybe this will help someone.

Comment: I had this exact situation. Changing my `Activity` to `AppCompatActivity` instead of `FragmentActivity` worked perfectly. Also didn't effect functionality.

Comment: wow exactly, I have recently changed `AppCompatActivity` to `FragmentActivity` for some testing then I forgot to change it back. Now after changing it back to `AppCompatActivity` icons are showing. Do you know reason behind this?

Answer (score 10):

Where did you put the source image file? Is that under the Drawable folder? If so, then create mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi image source for the image, and put them in mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi folders.

Comment: hmm i just noticed, that putting image inside anydpi folder will not work

Answer (score 8):

This is the solution that worked for me after checking the layout xml, theme etc. Just changing the "extends Activity" from your java class to "extends AppCompatActivity".

Should some of the previous suggested solutions worked for you, others having the same problem with ImageView image not showing might try this as well.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by extending `AppCompatActivity` and renaming my image to correct standard.
My image name (previously): **splash-1** (didn't worked).
And I tried renaming image name to **splash1**.
After that everything worked.
note: the image file might also be responsible for this problem.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/modified"` instead of `tools:srcCompat="@drawable/modified"`in XML files.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29939920)

Answer (score 4):

Try `android:background="@drawable/your_image"` instead of `app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_image"`

Answer (score 3):

Check for the following:

1. Are you invoking `setContentView` (for your splash screen) on the UI thread
2. Are there other activities (or views) that you're displaying too quickly after your splash screen (i.e. nullifying the splash screen `setContentView`)?
3. Trying using match_parent instead of wrap_content on the `ImageView` `layout_height` and `layout_width`.

Comment: The great answer and the exact same problem ecountered for me

Answer (score 3):

100% working code . same problem show in my code . but i am using AppCompatImageView after then show my image

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_calendar"
                />
```

Answer (score 2):

**Android ImageView Is Not Displaying Image?**

none of these solutions are not worked for me. what i did was i added these code lines in my manifest file

> android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
>
> android:largeHeap="true"

if these codes line didn't solve your problem try to **set your image view height and width**. not using wrap content or match parent. if your size didn't worked. try to **reduce the number** and retry. i think these solutions are helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Not related to this question but still sharing an experience, sometimes we set the source to the tools and then we expect a result (happened to me twice and took 15 minutes each time to resolve).

```
tools:srcCompat
//instead of 
android:srcCompat
```

Image source for tools is visible in android studio only.

Answer (score 1):

What format is your drawable file in? Android prefers using `.PNG` mostly.

Comment: what purpose you want to use image?do u want to make splash screen or other???nd mostly the image is in png format.try and check

Comment: the image is in .PNG format. and yea, it's a splash screen that I just want to display this image in the center of a black screen (as I check for updates from the server, etc. )

Comment: Is the image to big? Or does it need to be implemented onto your java file? And if you want to center it, you may want to use Gravity to do that.

Answer (score 1):

A null bitmap = unusable image.

This is the basis for how an image is actually used. When an image is used in android and it is assigned it actually converts the image into a bitmap, and depending on certain parameters being size and various other factors, it can fail, which would result in your image being converted and being returned as null due to some failure that occurred.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the image wasn't visible while choosing the image from the list of images.

Rebuilding the project fixed it for me.

**Build -> Rebuild Project**

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. I really cannot believe how simple it was. Though this may not be the issue for you, this fixed it for me. My image file was named 
ss-logo.png. Android Studio does not allow dashes in image files. Once I changed it to ss_logo.png, it worked perfectly. Only use letters, numbers, and underscores in your image file name. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your image color...If you are using the white background and if you use the white color image then it will not be displayed...Try changing your background container for the image to some other color or change your image color. I really faced this situation and wasted lot of time...I hope this will help someone...

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the name of your image
eg:"img-icon-butterfly.png" these type of names should be renamed and "-" should be removed so instead use names like "imgbutterfly.png"

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same problem. I tried rebuild but it did not help. Finally I **resized** the image from its original size of 2400x2400 to 1200x1200 using an online PNG resizer and then **compressed** it from 590KB to 150KB file size using an online compressor.

Comment: No it is not ...because that answer only mentions to reduce image size which i tried but it did not work...then i combined it with resizing the image which turned out to be the formula :)

Answer (score 1):

Try Changing from `ImageView` to `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView` in your layout file

Comment: That's what worked for me AppCompatImageView + app:srcCompat. Tks

Answer (score 0):

> **Don't** create **drawable** folder yourself. Recreate it with **Image Asset** option in android studio.

In my case, the problem was drawable folder itself. i had created drawable folder myself. it's not correct. in the android studio we should create drawable folder with Image Asset option. i didn't get the reason but now the problem is sloved.

Answer (score 0):

try making the image size a little less, I guess the android studio doesn't support the image with higher pixels .Anyway it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I copied/pasted a PNG image into the Drawable folder and set all the info and params in XML file

---> image showed in the Preview but not on actually device/emulator.

So--> In Java Activity, I recalled it programmatically:

```
  ImageView imview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IdFromXML);
    imview.setImageResource(0);
Drawable draw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.NameOfTheFileInFolder);
draw = (draw);
imview.setImageDrawable(draw);
```

Got it done!

Convert Image to PNG if necessary. Plenty free converters online.

Answer (score 0):

Image file name matters as well. Make sure when you name your image, there are no spaces. Use "_" instead or something

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. After a bit of work I found out that  if
I placed the image in the drawable(anydpi), which was being rendered in the design preview but not on the real device it was a problem. So, I placed the image inside simple drawable folder rather than drawable(anydpi). That fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Android Development like I am, READ THESE DOCS:

[Android Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities)

[Medium Article from a LinkedIn Android Dev](https://medium.com/web-factory-llc/byte-sized-bits-to-cleaner-android-code-drawable-dpi-837c7360121)

I've done iOS development for several years now and decided to branch out into Android development. I found that most of the time it is entirely to do with screen resolution (also mipmap is NOT for drawable images as mentioned before). 
None of these answers fixed my issues, I had to setup the standard resolution directories of `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi`, and `drawable-xxxhdpi`. These are all of the directories your emulator or devices will look at when searching for the correct resolution for the device setup. If you put your image in `drawable` alone, this could cause these folders to be overlooked by the device and that's when you get a high-resolution image being non-visible or crashing the app from memory errors. Be sure to check the dimensions of your image and make sure that you import it under the correct drawable directories to ensure the device scales the image accordingly.

My explanation is a small overview, but I do highly recommend reading the articles.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your logcat output as well. You may see an image similar to this one:

```
OpenGLRenderer 0x0000644a:0 Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (4203x2277, max=4096x4096)
```

If this is the case, decrease the image size.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in ImageView XML file

```
android:src="@drawable/splashscreen"
tools:srcCompat="@drawable/splashscreen"
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the layout alpha was set to 0 which is what went wrong.
Sometimes alpha comes by itself.
Anyway 0 alpha is the default value even if not mentioned.
So try to remove alpha as 0.
**0 alpha is = invisible!!**

Comment: alpha should be 1 (opaque) by default, are you sure?

Comment: `Sometimes alpha comes by itself` What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

in my case replacing   `tools:srcCompat` with  `android:srcCompat` in the xml tag of the image view solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

None of these work for Android WearOS

You need to use `android:src="@drawable/ic_check"` inside your `ImageView` for it to appear.

`app:srcCompat` and `android:srcCompat` do not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Many of the image related issues are solved by using the third party libraries like Picasso by Jake Wharton. I had unexplained issues with image loading and some times even getting out of memory error. That was especially cased by imaged edited (using Gimp for Mac). Picasso does the hard work of handling the memory and necessary caching etc.

http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: The point of the question is that the image is not being displayed. Picasso's purpose is completely different

Answer (score -1):

if your Image is not displaying in your code because of some layout errors
you can usetools:ignore="contentDescription"

**usetools:ignore="contentDescription"**

use this line in code.

Comment: does not make a difference